# iOS - Moved UIImageView reset to original position after animation, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiimageview, nsarray

I am currently frustrated with an issue i can't seem to find an answer for. I have a UIImageView that is being controlled by the user, moving 20 pixels left or right depending on the direction they press. At the same time, I am trying to animate it with an NSArray with a different button press. However, each time i animate the UIImageView, the position resets.

For example, I will move it say 80 pixels to the right, and as soon as the animation button is pressed, it shifts back to its original position before animating. It is extremely infuriating. Here is my code:

('pos' is a CGPoint set to (20,0) pixels)

```
-(IBAction)moveleft {

    player.center = CGPointMake(player.center.x-pos.x,player.center.y+pos.y);
}


-(IBAction)moveright {

    player.center = CGPointMake(player.center.x+pos.x,player.center.y+pos.y);
}



-(IBAction)animove {

isMove = TRUE;

    player.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0002.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0003.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0004.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0005.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0006.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0007.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0008.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0009.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"move0010.png"], nil];



    player.animationDuration = 0.35;
    player.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [player startAnimating];



}
```

To conclude, Both `-(IBAction)moveleft` and `-(IBAction)moveright`work fine, as does

`-(IBAction)animove`, yet once `animove` is excecuted, the UIImageView `player` moves back to its original position before the left or right movements were made.

any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: watch Stanford video 15 - Editable Text, Modal View Controllers you'll get everything what u looking for but its done for a single label, you can do it for your image view. The next video 16 - Core Motion, Segmented Control, and Alerts - YouTube let u do multiple animations together.

Comment: Could you show the code for startAnimating, and also explain us where the pos point is set

Answer (score 3):

Despite this being a very old question, I had the same problem and found the answer: UnCheck AutoLayout.

how to do that: http://www.raywenderlich.com/17811/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-13/smat-disable-autolayout

Good luck anyone who stumbles on this like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have that behavior...

I checked your code here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19438780/testAnim.zip

Seams to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try remembering the position when you move the object, and than resetting it when you hit the animation button.

```
-(IBAction)moveleft {
    rememberPosition = CGPointMake(player.center.x-pos.x,player.center.y+pos.y);
    player.center = rememberPosition; 
}

-(IBAction)moveright {
    rememberPosition = CGPointMake(player.center.x+pos.x,player.center.y+pos.y);
    player.center = rememberPosition;
}

-(IBAction)animove {
    player.center = rememberPosition;
    player.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...];
    player.animationDuration = 0.35;
    player.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [player startAnimating];
}
```